# when i want to print IEnumerable to console screen then i'm getting "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Linq_1.Objects.UserObject]"

Tags: c#, linq, console-application, ienumerable, tolist

I'm trying to learn Ienumerable with linq.

What I want to do is to print the userlist after filtering it with linq. But I am encountering such a console screen.

**Main Code:**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        LinqExtensions<UserObject> linq = new LinqExtensions<UserObject>();
        var users = new List<UserObject>()
        {
           new UserObject()
           {
               Id=1,
               FirstName="xx",
               LastName="yy",
               EmailAdress="zz@gmail.com",
               CreateDateTime=DateTime.Now
           },
           new UserObject()
           {
               Id=2,
               FirstName="aa",
               LastName="bb",
               EmailAdress="cc@gmail.com",
               CreateDateTime=DateTime.Now
           }
        };
        
        var userList = linq.Where_EqualsEvenID(users);
        Console.WriteLine(userList);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

**And Extensions Code:**

```
    public class LinqExtensions <T> where T:UserObject
{
    
    public IEnumerable<T> Where_EqualsEvenID(IEnumerable<T> TTypeIEnum)
    {
        return TTypeIEnum.Where(p => p.Id % 2 != 0).ToList();
    }
    public IEnumerable<T> Where_OddEvenID(IEnumerable<T> TTypeIEnum)

    {
        return TTypeIEnum.Where(p => p.Id % 2 != 0).ToList();
    }
    
    public IEnumerable<T> Where_EqualsId(IEnumerable<T> TTypeIEnum,int id)
    {
        return TTypeIEnum.Where(p=>p.Id==id).ToList();
    }
}
```

[**Console ScreenShot**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFGv7.png)

**Console Message:**
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Linq_1.Objects.UserObject]

Help me please, thanks a lot.

Comment: Right, so what did you *expect* to happen, and why? What was your expected output format, and where is `List<T>` documented to conform to that format when you implicitly call `ToString()` on it? Additionally, does `UserObject` override `ToString()`?

Comment: No, ToString is not defined as override in UserObject or BaseObject. What I expect is that I want to see List of UserObject in Console output.

Comment: "What I expect is that I want to see List of UserObject in Console output." That tells us basically nothing about the expected format. XML? JSON? Something else? Why do you have that expectation - what code do you expect to be formatting it?

Answer (score 2):

Why are you getting the type text instead of values?

- [`Console.WriteLine(Object)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?view=net-7.0#system-console-writeline(system-object)) writes the text representation of an object.
- To represent the object into text, it calls `.ToString()` method.
- If it is not overridden in your class, then it invokes [`.ToString()` default implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=net-7.0).
- This default implementation is nothing but returning the string representation of the current object

---

How to fix your issue?

To fix this issue, you override `ToString()` within the `UserObject` class.

```
public class UserObject
{
   ...

   public override string ToString()
   { 
       //You can include fields as per your need.
       return $"{this.FirstName} {this.LastName}";
   }  
}
```

Now while printing the list of `UserObject`, you need to iterate over each object of `UserObject` and print the details.

```
foreach(var userObj in userList)
   Console.WriteLine(userObj);
```

You can also use `string.Join()`,

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, userList));
```

This will print

```
xx yy
aa bb
```

Comment: `WriteLine()` doesn't care whether `ToString()` is implemented or not, it converts its argument to string according to the format specified. It is the `object.ToString()` which returns the type's name if not overriden.

Comment: @TanveerBadar, yes you are absolutely right and that is what I tried to convey in my first sentence. Let me know if I need to re-phrase it

Comment: @TanveerBadar, I updated my answer to explain the why part in detail

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar Thanks! This method is pretty self explanatory and worked very well. I didn't know WriteLine() calls ToString() method , thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop IEnumerable collection and use Json serialized(add Newtonsoft.Json extension to your project) to convert and print object in console.

Check below code

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;


namespace SampleExample
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            LinqExtensions<UserObject> linq = new LinqExtensions<UserObject>();
            var users = new List<UserObject>()
        {
           new UserObject()
           {
               Id=1,
               FirstName="xx",
               LastName="yy",
               EmailAdress="zz@gmail.com",
               CreateDateTime=DateTime.Now
           },
           new UserObject()
           {
               Id=2,
               FirstName="aa",
               LastName="bb",
               EmailAdress="cc@gmail.com",
               CreateDateTime=DateTime.Now
           },
           new UserObject()
           {
               Id=3,
               FirstName="zak",
               LastName="tos",
               EmailAdress="zak@gmail.com",
               CreateDateTime=DateTime.Now
           },
           new UserObject()
           {
               Id=4,
               FirstName="Michael",
               LastName="J",
               EmailAdress="mj@gmail.com",
               CreateDateTime=DateTime.Now
           }
        };

            var userList = linq.Where_EqualsEvenID(users);

            foreach (var item in userList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item, Formatting.Indented));
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public class LinqExtensions<T> where T : UserObject
        {
            public IEnumerable<T> Where_EqualsEvenID(IEnumerable<T> TTypeIEnum)
            {
                return TTypeIEnum.Where(p => p.Id % 2 == 0).ToList();
            }
            public IEnumerable<T> Where_OddEvenID(IEnumerable<T> TTypeIEnum)

            {
                return TTypeIEnum.Where(p => p.Id % 2 != 0).ToList();
            }

            public IEnumerable<T> Where_EqualsId(IEnumerable<T> TTypeIEnum, int id)
            {
                return TTypeIEnum.Where(p => p.Id == id).ToList();
            }
        }
        public static void localmethod1(object a, object b)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Local method." + a + "-" + b);
        }

        public static void DisplayNumbers(int min, int max)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("DisplayNumbers :" + (min + max));
        }
    }

    public class UserObject
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string EmailAdress { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreateDateTime { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

Result

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mxrJ.png)

Comment: I like this method done with a good point of view. Thank you so much. I didn't think of serialize :)